# Image is rotated when posting from windows phone app to ASP.NET MVC server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm working on a Universal Windows App for my Windows Phone, it's a very simple app which takes a photo using the front camera of the phone then posts the photo to an ASP.NET MVC server.

The photo is a selfie in portrait mode. When it gets posted to the server, it gets rotated for some reason and becomes a landscape photo at the server. I'm not sure why this happens, but I don't want the photo to get rotated. What is the best way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out the reason to this, but I have a solution to the problem that worked quite well for me. At the server side, you can check the meta data of the image and see if it was rotated. If that's the case, then you can simply de-rotate the image:

```
private static void DerotateIfRotatedWrongly(Image image)
    {
        if (image.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x0112))
        {
            var rotationValue = image.GetPropertyItem(0x0112).Value[0];
            switch (rotationValue)
            {
                case 1: 
                    // landscape, do nothing
                    break;

                case 8: 
                    // rotated 90 degrees right
                    // de-rotate:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    // bottom is up
                    // de-rotate:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;

                case 6: 
                    // rotated 90 degrees left
                    // de-rotate:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```